# Laravel 8 email validation using rfc,dns

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm trying to validate email using rfc,dns in Laravel 8 in local hosting. Some times it return that there is no email like that even if the email exist. Any help?

There is the validation code

```
$this->validate($request, [
        "email" => ["email:rfc,dns"],
    ]);
```

Comment: If you don't have active internet connection DNS validation will fail

Answer (score 0):

make sure your email is not resolving as local domain.
If you put you rule to validate dns, your email should resolve to a valid external domain. Otherwise if resolves email@mydomain to a local ip like 192.168 or 10.0 it will think that the email is not deliverable.

Just remove the DNS validation in your rule (,dns)

```
$this->validate($request, [
    "email" => ["email:rfc"],
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should make sure you have access to the internet for this to work.